# How Can i Compile My C++ Project?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, bluefish

it keeps telling me

```
gcc hello.cpp -o hello
gcc: error: hello.cpp: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

please anyone help

Comment: I think that error message is pretty clear. It can't find hello.cpp.

Comment: `hello.cpp` should present in current directory. Or you can try absolute path.

Comment: btw, you should compile with `g++` not `gcc` if you have `c++` code.

Answer (score 1):

The source file needs to be in the same path you invoke gcc or you can put the full path in there

```
gcc /home/username/Desktop/hello.cpp
```

or you can do cd /home/username/Desktop then invoke gcc from that given path.

Answer (score 0):

set your current directory where the .cpp file is